# Personal information in question

Tags: support, status-completed, moderation

I found a question that included an image with personal data, including names, surnames, what looks like tax identification number, and several numbers (probably salary related). I have edited it out of the question, but it remains in the history, and I think the question should be deleted (it is off topic, anyway) as soon as possible, before some bad people gets their hands on the data. I don't know how much harm can be done, but I wouldn't like to have this kind of details about me posted without my permission.

I have flagged it for moderator attention, how long will it take for the mods to get there?

Comment: I've never really seen a standard ETA.  Just remember not even talk about it in the comments.  However, I see that you have; I'd delete that comment, if I were you.  You don't want to draw more attention to it then you already have.

Comment: @Daedalus that is a good point, done.

Comment: What evidence do you have that the information was real and not just mocked up?

Comment: @slugster If I was to mock them, I would have made two rows. This person had a full screenshot. And considering the question was "do the job for me", I don't think he went as far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The moderator flag queue is very large so it may take anywhere from one day to a week (or maybe quicker if they notice this post).

Once a moderator does review the flag, they will do the following if they agree:

1. Delete the question so that not as many people can view it.
2. Edit out the personal information (if not done already).
3. <del>Ask a site developer to remove</del> [Redact edits including personal information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132117/what-should-i-do-if-a-user-posts-sensitive-information-as-part-of-a-question-or/132119#132119) from the edit history from the post. This also requires that another moderator agrees with the redaction. If this can be done quick enough, initial deletion may not be necessary.
4. Undelete the question (unless, of course, it should be deleted).

Then at some point, they will probably mark the flag as helpful.

Comment: For the record, it has now been fixed, and it seems it happened exactly as you described. From the time stamps, it was less than a day.