# Personal information in JsFiddle

Tags: discussion

I made a fiddle for my question but there was some personal information in the content. At first I did not realize I left the personal information in the fiddle, but then I got an answer from someone mentioning it. I checked the fiddle and confirmed that some personal information was in the fiddle.

I know this is my own fault, but I have edited the question. Is that a good thing or should I have kept it in?

Comment: Was the personal information actually *relevant* to the question? Note that it will still be visible in the revision history - if this is a data protection issue, you should flag the revision so a moderator can arrange have the history removed (see e.g. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268215/3001761).

Comment: But the problem is still in the awnser of someone

Comment: And the revisions of the questions are still there then

Comment: Then you will need to flag the answer for the same treatment, or make that clear in your flag on the question.

Comment: That'll teach you to make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ;)